# Parse.com: JSONObject cannot be cast to ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform, picasso

I'm trying to retrieve the image from Parse.com. In DataBrowser, if the image file is empty its crashing in code. so I'm handling this error by checking if file!=null.

Its crashing at this line `ParseFile file = (ParseFile) ob.get("image");` saying `JSONObject cannot be cast to ParseFile`.

So How to handle if Parse File is empty??

```
for (ParseObject ob : result) {
String perf = ob.getString("info");
ParseFile file = (ParseFile) ob.get("image");
if (file != null) {
    image_url = file.getUrl();
    } else {
         /*load some default image url*/
        image_url = "www.abc.com/image.png";
    }
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image_url).into(imageView);
    textView.setText(perf);
    layoutCards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Get(image) is return null. Nothing to cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

(Make sure in parse databrowser there is a field called "image" where you store parsefile)

```
ParseFile parseFile = ob.getParseFile("image");
```

then check:

```
if (parseFile != null && parseFile.getUrl() != null && parseFile.getUrl().length() > 0) {
            ...
}
```

Comment: Knock Knock!!Thanks for figuring out Dexter. In older versions of Parse I was using object.get("image"). In Parse-1.5.1.jar its object.getParseFile("image");

Answer (score 0):

How about catch the NullPointerException like this :

```
for(ParseObject ob : results) {
    try {
        ParseFile imageFile = (ParseFile) ob.get("image");

        imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // data has the bytes for the image
                    Log.d(TAG,"get image");
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }
       });
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"got no image");
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a image file to my parse db then I delete the image file, (but the raw is still exist, just the image file is deleted) and these code works on this circumstance.